# What should the iBook tag actually be for? Books or laptops?

Tags: discussion

While retagging [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58360/8823) to remove the 'iBooks' tag (which is clearly associated with Apple's e-book business, not their old iBook laptop line), I noticed that the singular [iBook tag](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibook) is frequently associated with *both* the books and laptop.

There are too many questions there (or so it seems to me) to do a quick and obvious reconciliation, so I wanted to ask for consensus: should the **iBook** tag be applied to the eponymous laptop, should it be a synonym for *iBooks*, both, neither?

I prefer the former option, since the older-model laptops carried the trade name iBook, while I've rarely ever heard an Apple-provided e-book referred to in the singular as an "iBook".

Comment: Is this question asking for opinion, or do you expect answers to be supported by fact?

Comment: @TestSubject528491 This question is tagged "discussion", so: the former. :)

Comment: I'm surprised. Questions such as this are usually closed precisely for that reason.

Comment: @TestSubject528491 ...On the Meta site, meant for discussion of how apple.stackexchange.com should operate? Are you sure you're not thinking of Ask Different itself?

Answer (score 12):

[ibooks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibooks) should apply exclusively to Apple's e-books offering. Maybe it should also be a synonym of the [ibookstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibookstore)? Perhaps not.

[ibook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibook) should apply exclusively to Apple's classic laptop line.

I can't think of a situation in which one would put the [ibook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibook) tag to signify a question about a specific e-book.

Comment: I've added a tag wiki to the iBook tag, attempting to make the intended usage clear. I guess we can just clean up the mis-tagged questions as we encounter them?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that [ibooks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibooks) should refer to the eBooks, but perhaps to avoid confusion, we could use [ibook-g4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibook-g4) and [ibook-g3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibook-g3) (or similar) as the tags for the hardware? A bit more distinction beyond plural/singular would probably be a useful thing.

Comment: Or maybe the tag would be ibook-laptop to make it clear.

Answer (score -1):

I agree in theory with @JasonSalaz's solution [ibooks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibooks) for the app and [ibook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibook) for the hardware.

Hopwever I think that users will not read the wiki and will carry on misusing the tags.

I think as iBook is now an old machine that a better solution would be to make the tag for the machine to be [ibook-laptop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibook-laptop) and remove an not allow [tag:iBook to be used]. Even then I would not be suprised to see machine related questions being wrongly tagged but this way would lead to the least errors.

Comment: iBook-laptop is clunky and not Apple's terminology (they've long used the term "notebook" and never "laptop"). The solution to people misusing a tag is to edit it so it is correct, not to make tagspace artificially awkward to accommodate people who can't be bothered to read what their tags mean and use them properly.

Comment: Good idea, @Mark.